# React get the input type=file value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have this element:

```html
<input type="file" id="newFile" onChange={handleFileChange} />
<input type="text" id="newMessage" onChange={handleMessageChange} />
<button onClick={uploadData}>Upload</button>
```

in function handleFileChange:

```js
const handleFileChange = event => {
  let input = event.target.files[0];
  if (!input) return;
  let data = new FormData();
  data.append("fileToUpload", input);
  setFile(data);
};
```

in function handleMessageChange:

```js
const handleMessageChange= event => {
  setMessage(event.target.value)
};
```

with **setFile** and **setMessage** is the setState hooks of react and those states are used as a payload to call API:

```
const [file, setFile] = useState()
const [message, setMessage] = useState()
```

The problem is: I want to send both **file data** and **message** in one API call, so I tried 2 ways:

1. set new FormData in func **uploadData** :

```js
const handleClick = async () => {
   let data = new FormData
   data.append("file", file) // expect to pass the file state to here but it not works
   data.append("message, message)    
   // Call API with payload = data...                
}
```

2. get the value of 2 inputs in the func **uploadData** :

```js
const handleClick = async () => {
  let inputFile = document.getElementById("newFile");
  let inputMessage = document.getElementById("newMessage");
  let data = new FormData();
  data.append("file", inputFile.value); // only got the file path (C://fakepath/....), not the file data
  data.append("message", inputMessage.value);
  // Call API with payload = data...
};
```

Both of 2 ways do not work. Can you help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna answer your question in a general way so anybody who wants to use it can go ahead. There is something called FileReader in html5 its called FileReader. You have to use the FileReader API.

```
function readImage(file) {
  // Check if the file is an image.
  if (file.type && file.type.indexOf('image') === -1) {
    console.log('File is not an image.', file.type, file);
    return;
  }

  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
    img.src = event.target.result;
  });
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

Comment: how can i use your answer in my case?

Comment: This might help https://web.dev/read-files/#toc-reading-files

Comment: you have to create a new instance of FileReader and pass your file as an argument in FileReader instance

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but this one hope it will work.
Change `.value` with `inputFile.files[0]`

```js
const handleClick = async () => {
  let inputFile = document.getElementById("newFile");
  let inputMessage = document.getElementById("newMessage");
  let data = new FormData();
  data.append("file", inputFile.files[0]); //<-- CHANGED .value to .files[0]
  data.append("message", inputMessage.value);
  // Call API with payload = data...
};
```

```html
<input type="file" id="newFile" onChange={handleFileChange} />
```